# Can we have an inner class inside a method?

Tags: java, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of class definitions inside a method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java)

Can we have inner class inside a method ?

Any code  sample will be helpful.

Comment: You can actually try this yourself you know... And also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
public final class Test {
  // In this method.
  private void test() {
    // With this local variable.
    final List<String> localList = new LinkedList<String>();
    // We can define a class
    class InnerTest {
      // Yes you can!!
      void method () {
        // You can even access local variables but only if they are final.
        for ( String s : localList ) {
          // Like this.
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Foo implements Runnable {
        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }

    Foo foo = new Foo();
}
```

I would recommend against it though, preferring anonymous inner classes where they're good enough, or nested classes *not* inside the method in other cases. If you need a named class within a method, that suggests you need to get at extra members it declares, which is going to get messy. Separating it into its own nested class (ideally making it static, to remove a bunch of corner cases) usually makes the code clearer.

Comment: There is one good use for local inner classes, namely the case where you need something like an anonymous class but where you need the class to have a constructor.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz: You can use initializer blocks for most of those cases - what are you doing in the constructor which requires it to be named?

Comment: Yes that is another way to do it. However, 'parameters' to such initializer blocks would then need to be declared final in the outer scope (the method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called **local inner class** - you'll find examples by using this term in a web search.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called a local class: [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)