# what's the benefit of defining some class inside a method?

Tags: java

Is there any benefit to define a class inside a method. I saw someone prefer to define some listener class inside a method, any real benefit to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of class definitions inside a method in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean **anonymous inner classes** or **local inner classes**. See [this article for the differences and the advantages](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/anonymous_innerclassestutorial.shtml) In my opinion, the biggest advantage is that the code is at the place where it is used and not in another file.

Answer (score 3):

It's done for two reasons:

- Locality of logic. Scatterring logically and tightly related parts of code makes it harder to follow.
- When you define a class inside a method, it [*closes in*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) over the local variables available in scope. This way unnecessary argumet passing is avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It is named InnerClass, and this allows you to instantiate an object that implements an interface or abstract class without the need to define it formally as a separated class. Listeners are good examples since it would be too costly to support a system that has every single listener implemented as a separated class.

A good reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html (Inner Classes topic)

Comment: I think he is not talking about nested Classes but inner classes. The doc you pointed to is talking aboiut nested Classes.

Comment: Additional link (specific for inner-class): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html.