# how to initiate a method which is inside another method?

Tags: java

I have the following case. now I need to call method Two from an other class, how do I do it? In java you can declare a class inside a method.

```
public class Name {
    void methodOne() {
        class InnerClass {
           void methodTwo() {
           }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You create an InnerClass instance and call the method, of course.

Comment: 1. create an instance of `InnerClass`. 2. use this instance and the `methodTwo`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it's not valid c#

Comment: C# or Java?  pick one...

Comment: I am not able to create instance for inner class

Comment: But you can't create class inside C# method (assuming C# is valid tag on the question)...

Comment: Okay let's clear this up: classes *can* be declared inside methods, in Java anyway.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov we can do it. kindly try it and then try to answer.

Comment: @PaulBellora yes it can be done

Comment: @PaulBellora - you right - looking more like Java code - method name start with lower case, probably question is mis-tagged.

Comment: c# or java? 

for java this question was already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java

Comment: @elnin0 guys try to understand my question. My class is inside another method and not inside another class

Comment: Valid Java, but you can't call `methodTwo()` from outside `methodOne()`. It's as simple as that. The question elnin0 linked is helpful as well.

Comment: for people who did not get the question, please do not rate it has unclear.. try to understand and then try to rate the question.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas what if both are defined public?  in elninO example inner class is private. kindly have a look

Comment: You can not declare a method-local class with the modifier `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this **in Java** and prints the message:

```
class Foo {
    void bar() {
        class Baz {
            void hi() {
                System.out.println("Hi");
            }
        }
        Baz baz = new Baz();
        baz.hi();
    }
}
```

For non-Java programmers, this would result very odd, but is the base for [anonymous classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

> now I need to call methodTwo from another class

Since the `Baz` class is inside the `bar` method, you can't use it outside this method. The only case when you can do that is when this `Bar` class implements a public interface (or extends a public [abstract]class) that can be consumed by the *another* class. For example:

```
interface Polite {
    void hi();
}

class Bud {
    void aMethod(Polite polite) {
        polite.hi();
    }
}

class Foo {
    void bar() {
        class Baz implements Polite {
            @Override
            public void hi() {
                System.out.println("Hi");
            }
        }
        Polite baz = new Baz();
        Bud bud = new Bud();
        bud.aMethod(baz);
    }
}
```

Comment: Except the OP wants to "call methodTwo from an other class", which isn't possible, unless of course that other class is also declared in the same method.

Comment: Baz is a "member" (local "variable" of type Class might be more accurate, although the funny thing is the "variable" doesn't get assigned a name) of the _method_ (Bar), not of the _class_ (Foo).  Hence the inner class is visible only inside the method, I presume.

Comment: @PaulBellora answer updated trying to give some light.

Comment: Inner hi method has to be public to make it work.. thanks

Comment: @Learner code fixed. Sorry, was just typing the code on answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks. How do we initialize interface in methos aMethod and what is the use of Polite baz = new Baz();
        Bud bud = new Bud();
        bud.aMethod(baz);

Comment: I would like to call the interface form the aMethod()

Comment: @Learner as you can see, you receive an instance of the `Polite` interface in the `aMethod` so you just have to initialize it outside. In this case, the implementation of this interface is done by the `Baz` class inside the `Foo#bar` method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29012/discussion-between-learner-and-luiggi-mendoza)

Comment: It would be possible to call the method elsewhere if 1) the inner class instance was returned and 2) it implemented an interface visible to the callee.

Comment: @ArtB yes, that's covered in the second code example.