# error message "Illegal Start of Expression"?

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors

```
// Simple program to understand pass by reference 
import java.util.*;
public class HelloDate {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         class Number                     // Contains only an integer
         {
             int i;
         }
         static void f(Number k)           // <<--- Illegal start of expression ???
         {
             k.i = 22;
         } 
         Number n1 = new Number();        // New object of Number
         n1.i = 9;
         f(n1);                           //Passing an object
         System.out.println(n1.i);        // Print
      }
    }
```

The code is showing an error on `static void f(Number k)`. Should I put the method `void f()` in a class? If yes, why is that necessary?

Comment: Right now the method `f` isn't inside your class, it's inside another method (`main`).

Comment: This works in Groovy :)

Comment: You mean other than the numerous syntax errors that make what you've posting completely not valid code?

Answer (score 5):

Methods have to be members of classes, they can only be placed in the body of a class.

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid to nest methods within other methods but you can define a [`inner class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) withing a method and gain a similar effect. This previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java) has some great examples.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you have a method `f()` directly inside another method `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you put a class in a method, it is called a local class, whose scope is only in the method.

```
     class Number // local class
     {
         int i;
     }
```

However, you cannot put a method directly in another method. You can only put a method in a class. Take your code as an example, you can put `f` either in `HelloDate` or `Number`.

If you put `f` in `HelloDate`, you need to put `Number` in `HelloDate`, too. Otherwise, the argument of `f`, `Number k`, will refer to `java.lang.Number` instead of the `Number` defined in `main`.