# Illegal start of expression for static classes?

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java. I want to display a Jframe with two buttons in it. 
Upon clicking each button a different JOptionPane message should show.
However I'm getting the error `Illegal start of expression` on both the `static class` declarations.

can anyone explain why? I've tried moving the static classes but still the same error.

Here is my code...

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class main { 

    public main() { 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { 

                    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your name?", "Enter your name", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    System.out.println("\nWelcome, "+ name + ".");  
                    System.out.print(terms);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to SkyWhale, " + name + ".\n" + deets + "\n" + terms , "Welcome, " + name + ".", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                    JFrame control = new JFrame("SkyWhale");
                      control.setVisible(true);
                      control.setSize(500,200);
                      control.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                      JButton chatbtn = new JButton("Live Chat");
                      JButton editorbtn = new JButton("Editor");
                      control.add(panel);
                      panel.add(chatbtn);
                      panel.add(editorbtn);

                      chatbtn.addActionListener(goToChat());
                      editorbtn.addActionListener(goToEdit());

                     static class goToEdit implements ActionListener { 
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Code goes here...", "Editor", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        }
                      }
                     static class goToChat implements ActionListener { 
                        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conversation...", "Live Chat", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        }
                      }

                    }

                }   



        }
```

Comment: You've got static classes declared in a method body. That's not allowed.

Comment: So If I close the method and add them after, would that work?

Comment: It is legal. As to if it will work, that depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring `static` classes in a method is illegal in Java. You can declare local classes, without the `static` keyword.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    class Foo {
        public void bar() {
            System.out.println("inside Foo#bar()");
        }
    }

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar();
}
```

Or you can take them completely out of the method. Either declare them in their own compilation unit, ie. a `java` file, or as [inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), or as a `static` [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Related:

- [Use of class definitions inside a method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java)