# Convention on Classes Inside Methods

Tags: java, conventions

I recently came across some seemingly shocking code. For the years I have been programming with Java, never have I seen a class inside a method, yet the user said it was common practice. I tried checking the Oracle Code Conventions documents, but nothing pertaining to this popped up.

The code, showing relevant parts, is below:

```
public void start(){
    //...
    class startListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            started = true;
        }
    }
    panel.getStartButton().addActionListener(new startListener());
    //...
}
```

[These do seem to compile just fine](http://ideone.com/kMqGKg)

**What are the rules regarding classes inside methods?**

Comment: It's common to have anonymous classes, not what you are showing. There's really no reason to have them there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am well-aware of anonymous classes and use them frequently. The difference is that those are documented.

Comment: Use a [Local Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java) instead.

Comment: @Scott thanks for that! I wasn't aware it was under that name, so this is then a copy. I'll flag it to be closed then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a **local class**. From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html):

> You can define a local class inside any block (see Expressions, Statements, and Blocks for more information). For example, you can define a local class in a method body, a for loop, or an if clause.
>
> A local class has access to the members of its enclosing class... However, a local class can only access local variables that are declared final.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen lot of code like this, primarily SWT Code for associating listeners. Though I would have coded it using anonymous local class rather than the named one.

```
public void start(){
     panel.getStartButton().addActionListener(new startListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            started = true;
        }
    });
}
```

but again this could be just my personal preference.