# Class Inside Method

Tags: java

```
public class Demo 
{

    public void met(Object d)
    {

        class my {
            public String Work(String s){
                return s+",JAVA";
            }
        }
        d=new my().Work("Hello");//statement 1
        System.out.println(d);//statement 2

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Demo().met(new Object());
    }

}
```

I don't know it's asked before or not. Here in this class `Demo` I am creating class `my`.

When I put statement 1 and 2 before class it gives me error but when I put  it after class that's okay.

So it means when I call method, class is loaded and class file is created named `Demo$1my.class` so that if I put statement 1 and 2 after class it works. Is it So?

My Question is can I create object of `my` class from main method and How?

Comment: Your naming conventions are confusing..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of class definitions inside a method in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I create object of my class from main method and How?

No. Only the `met` method knows anything about the class. If you want to use the class outside that method, you should declare it either as a nested class within `Demo`, or as a completely separate non-nested class.

Personally I would try to avoid nested classes as far as possible - they have odd restrictions, you can often end up creating inner classes instead of nested classes by accidentally forgetting the `static` modifier, and they're generally a pain.

Comment: Why would someone have a class *inside* a method? Specially when it's not *anonymous*..

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I've used it precisely *once* that I can remember- when I wanted to declare a specific exception which I then used in a callback, and then catch that particular exception.

Comment: I'm just curious, why didn't you declare the class *outside* the method? Can you please post a small example of that? I really want to know when it's better to have a class *inside* a method.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I didn't want any other code to know about the class, basically. There's no reason any other class would *need* to know about the class.