# Illegal modifier for the nested class

Tags: java

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private int N; // size of the list
    private Node first;
    private Node last;


    public Deque() {


        private class Node {
            private Item item;
            private Node next;
            private Node prev;

        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error that I have an illegal modifier for my private class Node and that only final or abstract is permitted. But the Node class can't stand on its own so I don't think static is needed. Is there something wrong with how the item and the Nodes are declared in the private class? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: defining class inside constructor?

Comment: You seem to be trying to declare a class inside another class's constructor. You probably mean it to be inside the main body of the `Deque` class, not in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define classes in blocks (like methods and constructors), they are called [Local classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).

However, just like you can't declare a local *variable* as `private`, `protected` or `public`, you also can't declare a local class with an access modifier - because it doesn't make sense to. A local class is only visible inside the defining method.

If you *really* intend to declare a local class, remove the access modifier. But since you are declaring fields in the top-level class of type `Node`, you can't declare it as a local class: just move it outside the constructor.

---

Just picking up on your comment about "I don't think static is needed": I don't think `static` is *not* needed. Adding `static` to nested classes should be your default action, unless you actually need to refer to the containing `Deque` instance from the `Node` instances.

The thing is that each of the `Node` classes will have a hidden reference to the `Deque`, in order that you can access the `Deque` instance via `Deque.this`. If you don't need this reference, you can cut down on the memory used by not using it, which you do by making the nested class `static`.

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is basically sound. The main flaw is that you're attempting to define the class inside the constructor whereas you should be defining it directly inside `Dequeue`:

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private class Node {
        private Item item;
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;
    }

    ...
}
```

Defining a class inside a method is permissible, but it's not what you need here. For background, see [Use of class definitions inside a method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java)